.NET 8 Source Generator JSON serializes to empty value
I'm currently making a few tests with this feature to implement on an API that I'm working on.
I have an API in .NET 8, using FastEndpoints, and I'm trying to serialize the api input and output through Source Generator. I made the input work, but the output for some reasons comes empty "{}".

My code:
WeatherForecastController.cs
public class WeatherForecastController : Endpoint<DtoIn, DtoOut>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("/test");
        Description(b => b.Produces(200));
        AllowAnonymous();
    }
    public override async Task HandleAsync(DtoIn req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await SendOkAsync(new DtoOut()
        {
            Surname = req.Name + "Teste"
        }, ct);
    }
}

public class DtoIn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class DtoOut
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
}

Program.cs

using FastEndpoints;
using FastEndpoints.Swagger;
using WebApplication1;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseFastEndpoints( c =>
{
    c.Serializer.Options.TypeInfoResolver = SourceGenerator.Default;
});
app.UseSwaggerGen();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

SourceGenerator.cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using WebApplication1.Controllers;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    [JsonSerializable(typeof(DtoIn))]
    [JsonSerializable(typeof(DtoOut))]
    [JsonSourceGenerationOptions(
    WriteIndented = true,
    GenerationMode = JsonSourceGenerationMode.Default,
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonKnownNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    )]
    internal partial class SourceGenerator : JsonSerializerContext
    {
    }
}

project.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <JsonSerializerIsReflectionEnabledByDefault>false</JsonSerializerIsReflectionEnabledByDefault>
    <EnableConfigurationBindingGenerator>true</EnableConfigurationBindingGenerator>
    <EnableRequestDelegateGenerator>true</EnableRequestDelegateGenerator>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FastEndpoints" Version="5.30.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="FastEndpoints.Swagger" Version="5.30.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.6.2" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I've been trying to make this work for at least three days with no success.
Does anyone have any idea what is wrong? Any helps would be appreciated
Repository with the error: https://github.com/Skinify/source-generator-error

Can't reproduce, try to response a hard-coded json string and restart your app, I suspect you visited a wrong api.

It works when i change de endpoint return to string and return a hardcoded string json, or when i remove the line "[JsonSerializable(typeof(DtoOut))]" in the SourceGenerator file

Here is an repo with the error https://github.com/Skinify/source-generator-error

You can vote to reopen your question. I ran your project and found that the difference is that my project targets .net9, and if I switch to .net8, it will not output. I found that the solution is not to set TypeInfoResolver on startup, but to use SerializerContext<SourceGeneratior>() in the Configure method instead. This is suggested here: https://fast-endpoints.com/docs/model-binding#source-generators

Thx for the feedback, i will be trying this aproach

It worked, now im searching for a way to configure the SerializerContext globally, probably i will just update to .net 9 to keep using the TypeInfoResolver sintax

This is a bug and will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/FastEndpoints/FastEndpoints/issues/783
